# Android Pro-guard duplicate zip entry in .aar file

Tags: android, android-proguard

In my project, i included two .aar libraries and both aar libraries have a commmon .jar file in their libs folder. 
When i try to obfuscate my code using pro-guard

```
>Error:Execution failed for task ':CpcCaenSample:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
 java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\CpcSerialCommunication-1.0.4\jars\libs\d2xx.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [d2xx.jar:com/ftdi/j2xx/BM_REQUEST_TYPE.class]))
```

My proguard file is

```
> -libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CaenRfidLibrary-1.0.1.aar
-libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CpcHdkCone-1.7.1.aar
-libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CpcHdkIntrabet-1.1.3.aar
-libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CpcHdkVoterDevice-1.0.3.aar
-libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CpcPowerMgmt-2.6.0.aar
-libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CpcSerialCommunication-1.0.4.aar
-libraryjars  D:\Projects\Cone\CpcCaenSample\CpcCaenSample\libs\CpcUtilsLib-4.0.0.aar

>-keep public class com.caen.*
-keep public class com.ftdi.*
-keep public class com.ftdi.j2xx.*
-keep public class com.ftdi.j2xx
-keep public class com.ftdi.d2xx.*
-keep public class com.ftdi.j2xx.BM_REQUEST_TYPE
-keep public class com.ftdi.d2xx.BM_REQUEST_TYPE

>-keep class com.ftdi.j2xx.** { native <methods>; }
-keep class com.ftdi.j2xx { native <methods>; }
-keep class com.ftdi { native <methods>; }

>-verbose
```

I am using android studio 1.5.1.

Kindly share solution.

Answer (score 0):

its because you have added `CaenRfidLibrary` two times in `libs` folder, this could happen sometimes when you have multiple versions of same library in `libs` folder.

and second option could be you have also added the dependency in `gradle.build` of this library. So check both places and remove duplicate enteries and the clean and build `APK` again.

Hope it helps